# Programmatically create MS Word file without having MS Word installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ms-word

How can I create Word files in C# using Visual Studio 2008, without Word on my PC?

Do I need to have Word installed on my PC, to be able to create Word files using Visual Studio 2008?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [Open XML Format SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en):

> The 2007 Microsoft® Office system introduces a new file format that is based on XML called Open XML Formats. Microsoft Office Word 2007, Microsoft Office Excel® 2007, and Microsoft Office PowerPoint® 2007 all use these formats as the default file format.
>
> Open XML formats are useful for developers because they are an open standard and are based on well-known technologies: ZIP and XML. Microsoft provides a library for accessing these files as part of the WinFX technologies in the System.IO.Packaging namespace.
>
> The Open XML Format SDK is built on top of the System.IO.Packaging API and provides strongly typed part classes to manipulate Open XML documents.

Comment: There is a newer version of the SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks; never used it and just did a quick search. You could just have edited the post, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Open XML SDK.

You don't need Word installed.

A nice feature of Visual Studio is that you can drag/drop a docx onto it, and explore its structure and see its XML.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the version of the Word file. Starting with Word 2007 Microsoft implemented the .docx-Format which is essentially an XML file inside a ZIP-archive. The format of the XML file is well documented and I believe there are lots of projects out there that are capable of creating those files.

Alternatively take a look at the [Open Document Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument). It's "more open" and Word 2007+ is capable of opening files created with it.